# Microsoft.Owin.Cors doesn't return `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

Many blog postings out on the web today say that with a WebAPI 2.0 project and OWIN, enabling CORS is easy.

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

However, I've never seen an `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` returned from my API, either in a response to a GET or an OPTIONS preflight.

I've altered my `UseCors` setup code to explicitly set a list of header names to expose in the CORS policy.

I haven't the CORS knowledge to assert that `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` package is broken, though I have a hunch that it is and that blogger's are only testing primitive APIs.

Comment: Microsoft.Owin.Cors was for webapi 1. WebAPI v2 uses System.Web.Http.Cors.  That's not to say its easy.  It's horrible. It works great except when it doesn't work at all. There are hacks necessary to work with oauth and cors.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks. The Owin package is shipping still and should be fixed or marked obsolete, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Armed with information from another question on here, I think the library is broken in respect to the CORS specification.

[CORS - When to return `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272199/cors-when-to-return-access-control-expose-headers)

I'll switch to using the `System.Web.Http.Cors` package that @Thomas mentions in his comment above.

Comment: Did this actually work? I swapped to using the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors v5.2.7 instead of Microsoft.Owin.Cors but still didn't see the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in my response headers from the initial preflight for a GET. Am I doing something wrong?